# Three parallel plates, approximated as black bodies

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, thermal-radiation

Consider three parallel plates, which can be approximated as ideal black bodies.  If the left plane is kept at temperature $T$, and the rightmost one at $2T$, what is the temperature of the middle one?

I'm not sure how to approach the problem. I'm looking for a conceptual explanation of this problem, not a worked out solution. Where does one begin when considering black body radiation of this type?

---

EDIT: After consulting the problem with my professor, I came to this solution, which he confirmed.

For the plates A, B, and C in order and by the Stefan-Boltzman law, $$ P_A = \sigma T_A^4A \ , P_B = \sigma T_B^4A \ , P_C=\sigma T_C^4A \\ P_B = P_A + P_B \Rightarrow \sigma T_B^4A=\frac{\sigma A (T_A^4 + T_C^4)}{2} \\ \Rightarrow T_B^4=\frac{(T)^4+(2T)^4}{2}=\frac{17}{2}T^4 \\ \therefore T_B = \bigg( \frac{17}{2} \bigg)^{\frac{1}{4}} T $$

Is this correct?

Comment: At equilibrium, energy in equals energy out.  What's the difference in energy output between $T$ and $2T$?

Comment: $T$. So, the problem is as simple $2T-T$? Let's say the middle plate was at temperature $T$, does this mean the outermost plates will also be at $T$ regardless of the distance between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose B receives thermal energy at the rate $P_A$ from the front face of A and $P_C$ from the back face of C. B will reach an equilibrium temperature at which the power $P_B$ it radiates from *both* its faces equals the sum $P_A+P_C$.

The calculation has to make use of the Stefan-Boltzmann Law of black body radiation, together with the fact that B is emitting from both faces while receiving radiation from only one face each of A and C. You must assume that the temperatures of A and C are controlled so they are not affected by the radiation from B.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55217/discussion-on-answer-by-sammy-gerbil-three-parallel-plates-approximated-as-blac).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equilibrium condition of these plates ( say A, B and C in order) i.e. when the amount of energy radiated from A to B is the same as that radiated from B to C.

Then think of [Stefan-Boltzmann's Law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/stefan.html). I hope you will get your answer.

Comment: Using your response along with Sammy Gerbil, I came to a possible solution. (See edit) Is my understanding of this problem correct?

Comment: @Kosta Please check the link. I have changed it. The law is better stated as $P \propto (T-T_c)^4$.